# Edit HTML-Code of specific Joomla Page

Tags: joomla-3.x, url, file-upload, jhtml, beginner

I am a Joomla Beginner and would like to know, how I can edit the HTML-Code of a specific webpage in Joomla.

I am not talking about editing an article, but the whole URL. And just a single one! Is there a way to upload a HTML-File that replaces a specific URL?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post the URL of the page you are wanting to change?

Comment: What you are asking doesn't seem very clear to me.  Can you provide some context to what you are asking? What are you currently getting and what do you want?

Comment: I want to change the following URL, without changing the template or components: https://www.dormo-novo.at/onlineshop/product/view/5/14.html

Answer (score 1):

Joomla is a PHP based content management system and web pages are built dynamically depending on which template, component, modules and plugins are associated with the page.

HTML can't easily be edited directly although there are extensions that allow you to add and change code. For example:

- the free or paid version of [Regular Labs Sourcerer](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sourcerer) allows you to insert code into an article or module
- the free or paid version of [Regular Labs ReReplacer](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/rereplacer) allows you to change existing html code on the page to alternative code
- [EasyScript](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/easyscript) (free) can be used to insert CSS or JavaScript code into the header

Rather than trying to edit code directly, the best practice is to override existing code so that your changes are not overwritten by template or other extension changes in future. For more details see:

https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried physically creating a file at `/onlineshop/product/view/5/14.html` with the replacement HTML code? Works when I tested it just now.

If a physical file exists at that request Joomla shouldn't come in to the picture. The server should serve that physical file instead. This is assuming you're running on an Apache server and your .htaccess is set up correctly (which it looks like it is)

Why this should work:

When someone requests `dormo-novo.at/onlineshop/product/view/5/14.html` from your server the server will discover that `/onlineshop/product/view/5/14.html` is not a real folder or file on your system. However, your .htaccess file it tells the server, "hey, if someone requests a folder or file that doesn't exist, send that request through Joomla so that Joomla can attempt to handle it" (That's how Joomla SEF URLs work). But, if the folder/file **does** exist then the server will serve that folder/file instead of redirecting the request through Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing is to create a new article from scratch and then link that new article to the Menu item that was previously linked to byt he old article you are replacing.

I am using this what you are asking whn you say " I am not talking about editing an article, but the whole URL. And just a single one! Is there a way to upload a HTML-File that replaces a specific URL"

You can use copy and paste to use the old text if you want to keep some of it but I am sure you know about this.

Answer (score 0):

I have just noticed that you have posted a link to your article so I suggest go to:

Content >> Articles

Now locate your page that you want to edit.  Click on it and it will open in your default editor.  You can now edit the section of the page and then you need to save it by clicking on the grenn button on the top left corner that says "Save".

Good luck.